# Link a #div and URL

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, hyperlink

Hey guys is it possible to link a div and url? Basically I want 2 links in one . One link to target the #div and one to target the actual site url in the div.

I am targeting a div but need the url to load in the div.

```
<a href="http://site.com/product/product-link" class="class-here">
```

I can only access the div using this url:

```
<a href="#modal" class="class-here">
```

Better way to describe it would be like this, but this does not work obviously:

```
<a href="http://site.com/product/product-link" target="#modal" class="second">
```

I am hiding the div #modal in these tags:

```
{{#product_page}}

Content is here

{{/product_page}}
```

Hard one to explain, so any more detail let me know.

Comment: Are you asking how to cause the browser to scroll to a div and at the same time to change the HTML of that div to be the same as that of another HTML document?

Comment: no, I want to target the url and div. I want the URL to load in the div #modal if that is an easier explanation...

Comment: @pete I thought the same thing, maybe there is a jquery method of doing this?

Comment: yes you can use an onclick on your anchor and do something like: `<a href="#modal" class="class-here" onclick="$('#modal').load('http://site.com/product/product-link');">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution to work:

The HREF link:

```
<a href="javascript:$.closeit({ direction: 'left', href: 'http://site.com/product/product-link' })">
```

Places this script at the bottom of my page:

```
<script>

    $(".class-here").closeit({ direction: "left", modal: true });
</script>
```

Thank you for everyone who assisted me.

Answer (score 3):

You were close, it is simply this:

```
 <a href="http://site.com/product/product-link#modal">
```

You can link to any id by appending it to the end of the url, as an example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670493/link-a-div-and-url#16670537) is a link to my comment

Comment: No luck there the div #modal is a jquery tool known as pageslide

Comment: @Nico You can't link to a jQuery tool, you link to an element through its ID. If you have something like `<div id="pageslide"></div>` you would append `#pageslide` instead of `#modal`.

Comment: the id #modal is simply a hidden CSS div. It wraps itself around {{#product_page}}.

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand you want to do but this perhaps work

The id attribute can be used to create a bookmark inside an HTML document.

```
<div id="tips">Useful Tips Section</div>
Create a link to the "Useful Tips Section" inside the same document:

<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
Or, create a link to the "Useful Tips Section" from another page:

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm#tips">
Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)